# Bluetooth low energy connection interval on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The Apple Bluetooth Design Guidelines say that connection interval should be set as such on the peripheral

```
Interval Min ≥ 20 ms
Interval Min + 20 ms ≤ Interval Max
```

When setting min to 20 ms, max to 40 ms, I expect to get an acceptance from the iPhone and lowest available interval, but the iPhone always set 37.5 ms connection interval. Trying to push the max value down gives a rejected status from the iPhone, which then set the connection interval to ~100 ms.

Is it possible to get this down to 20 ms (since this is the minimum from Apple guidelines) in some way? What is the actual minimum? According to my observations, the `Interval min` can be set to 30 ms, without making any difference.

Answer (score 2):

I have been experimenting with this recently.  This does not follow their guidelines so I'm not sure why it works, but using the following connection setting I was able to get an interval of 18.75 ms from an iPad:

- min interval = 10 ms
- max interval = 20 ms
- latency = 0
- timeout = 100 ms

Comment: Yes, this is appearently a bug which should be "fixed" in iOS6. No one knows why it works :P

Comment: And how do you people change MIN and MAX interval? Can you post code which does this operation? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I also want to know, how to set connection interval from iOS application. Please let me know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth SIG defines connection interval min and max range values = 7.25msec to 4000msec. Implementation can choose any value in this range as connection interval min or max. However, the connection interval min shall not be greater than connection interval max.
The minimum value depends on the battery considerations of the Peripheral and the maximum connection interval depends on the buffers available on the Peripheral. Iphone setting these values to 37.5 ms give us a hint that the buffers available on the Peripheral are constant. You can try to change this parameter and see if now you see the connection interval to be different.

Comment: Absolutely not. iPhone is not able to read buffer states on peripheral, and changing the parameters do not work (except for a bug I found). iOS 5 appearently only supports this connection interval (37.5), but should be a bit better in iOS6 according to their support. I am making the peripheral from the ground up, so I have good control over it, and changing the connection parameters doesn't matter at all